# Selecting Repeat Dates In SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a query that looks like this right now

```
 Select program_name, provider_name, patient_name, service_date
 From Table
 Order By program_name, provider_name, patient_name
```

Here is sample output:

```
program name     provider_name     patient name     service_date
pcare            john smith        Washingto        1/1/2014
pcare            john smith        Washington       1/5/2014
pcare            john smith        Obama            1/6/2014
pcare            john smith        Obama            1/6/2014
pcare            john smith        Bush             1/7/2014
pcare            john smith        Bush             1/18/2014
pcare            john smith        Clinton          1/18/2014
```

What I want to do is select patients who got more than 1 service on the same day. So the only thing I want is

```
pcare            john smith       Obama             1/6/2014
pcare            john smith       Obama             1/6/2014
```

How could I do this?

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that would be to write:

```
select program_name, provider_name, patient_name, service_date
from tablename
group by program_name, provider_name, patient_name, service_date
having count(*) > 1
```